# PVC to ABS on vent pipe

Tags: pvc, abs

The previous homeowner tapped into the ABS vent pipe to installed an ABS sanitary wye for a vanity he added.

I'm now removing the vanity and need to install a stud where the wye is.  My intent was to cut out the wye and install a piece of PVC into the vent pipe.

There will never be water in that pipe, it's just a vent.

What is the proper way to connect those?  Do I need a mechanical connection like a Fernco, or can I use the adhesive in the green can?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Unrelated to the question you are asking, I can't visualize the actual changes you are making. It feels like you are trying to hack together something. If you aren't sure the way you are changing the piping is correct, I suggest asking another question with details and pictures preferably.

Comment: In most markets, ABS and PVC are both available, so when repairing an ABS system, best to just use ABS. The multipurpose cement is out there, of course, but so are ABS pipe and ABS couplings...

Answer (score 3):

ABS to PVC Cement is the way to go for the connection.

Depending on the vent layout, assuming there will never be water in it is a false assumption.  Even if it is above the highest drain, rain falls into the vent stack normally and water likes to follow surfaces.

Comment: And water will tend to go up if no other way because of a blockage.